# Streaming data in c++

Tags: c++

This is the code that streams the data i see when i run `sampleclient.exe` for a rigid body?
What if I wanted to use the x y z qx qy qz qw point for other calculation? are they stored in an array i can access to do calculations in real time? I'm kinda of new at this, isn't `RigidBodies[i]` an array, but it value keeps pointing to a different value...

```
printf("Rigid Bodies [Count=%d]\n", data->nRigidBodies);

for(i=0; i < data->nRigidBodies; i++)
{
    printf("Rigid Body [ID=%d  Error=%3.2f]\n", data->RigidBodies[i].ID,  
    data->RigidBodies[i].MeanError);

    printf("\tx\ty\tz\tqx\tqy\tqz\tqw\n");

    printf("\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\t%3.2f\n",
        data->RigidBodies[i].x,
        data->RigidBodies[i].y,
        data->RigidBodies[i].z,
        data->RigidBodies[i].qx,
        data->RigidBodies[i].qy,
        data->RigidBodies[i].qz,
        data->RigidBodies[i].qw);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what problems you are having exactly. What line is causing you problems?

Comment: I don't know what a `RigidBodies` is, but from the context, `data` is a pointer to a structure that has a `RigidBodies` member that is an array.  Iterating the `data->RigidBodies' array with the array index `i` is what is causing the different values to be printed (one for each iteration of the loop).

Comment: MY current project is to create a application that streams the data from a motion capturing system called Optitrack. This system comes with an SDK called NatNet which comes with sample client code. The Rigidbodies refers to the body that i am tracking. Data points to the value of the (x,y,z) and (qx,qy,qz) rotations. I need to figure out a way to store those values in an array for future use. Right now it just print out the data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that the for loop prints different values each time.  This is because of the line:

```
for(i=0; i < data->nRigidBodies; i++)
```

Each time the loop runs `i` is incremented by one such that the array `data->RigidBodies` is accessed at a different index.

We could even "expand" the loop to be the following:

```
i=0;
printf("Rigid Body [ID=%d  Error=%3.2f]\n", data->RigidBodies[i].ID,  
data->RigidBodies[i].MeanError);
..
i=i+1;
printf("Rigid Body [ID=%d  Error=%3.2f]\n", data->RigidBodies[i].ID,  
data->RigidBodies[i].MeanError);
..
```

While you are using the same array each time, you are accessing a different element inside of it. The **index** tells us what item in the array we want.